# PHP array sort by number of items

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I need to sort my array-based on the number of elements in the inner array.
It's my current array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2-3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5-9
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5-9
            [1] => 2-3
        )

)
```

I need to sort the array by this format.

```
Array
(
[3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5-9
            [1] => 2-3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5-9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2-3
        )

[0] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do it:

```
<?php

$a = [
   [], ['2-3'], ['5-9'], ['5-9', '2-3']
];

$f = fn ($b, $c) => count($c) <=> count($b);
usort($a, $f);
print_r($a);
```

https://php.net/function.usort

Answer (score 1):

i hope this answer help you

```
$result  = array();
$sorter  = array();
foreach($values as $key => $vals){
  $sorter[$key]= count($vals);
}
arsort($sorter);
foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {
  $result[$ii]=$values[$ii];
}
```

output [image]